# Multiline regex not working for filebeat but working in goplay tester

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have filebeat->ES setup.no logstash.
I have logs like below :

```
2020 Feb 11 06:56:30:554 GMT -0500 DEBUG [LogPool$0] com.ZU.digital.utilityservices.logging.Logging - EAI-DEBUG | ProcessOrderStatus.rule: Id - : OrderStatusNotification Payload : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:OSN >
ns0:merchantID200142</ns0:merchantID>
ns0:orderCode2003787391047586</ns0:orderCode>
ns0:lastEventCAPTURED</ns0:lastEvent>
ns0:paymentAmount12.90</ns0:paymentAmount>
ns0:paymentCurrencyEUR</ns0:paymentCurrency>
ns0:paymentCreditDebitINDC</ns0:paymentCreditDebitIND>
ns0:additionalData
ns0:data
ns0:name/
ns0:value/
</ns0:data>
</ns0:additionalData>
</ns0:OSN>
2020 Feb 11 06:56:30:554 GMT -0500 DEBUG [LogPool$0] com.ZU.digital.utilityservices.logging.Logging - Masking input XML in maskEntireXml
```

I have multiline pattern as :

```
multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{4}[[:space:]]'

  # Defines if the pattern set under pattern should be negated or not. Default is false.
  multiline.negate: true

  # Match can be set to "after" or "before". It is used to define if lines should be append to a pattern
  # that was (not) matched before or after or as long as a pattern is not matched based on negate.
  # Note: After is the equivalent to previous and before is the equivalent to to next in Logstash
  multiline.match: after
```

but each line is treated as single event. Regex is tested in playgolang and working fine .I want logs as single event between dates

Comment: when i test a  pattern '^error: ' and give line input that starts with "error" it is giving expected output . but not working when using  ^[0-9]{4} and giving input that starts with "2020" etc

Answer (score 1):

Got resolved after making negate : true